# Android Marquee in TextView truncated and scrolls only in landscape

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, ellipsis

I am facing the following two *related (?)* problems:

1. Although the text is scrolling automatically in landscape mode, it
   does not scroll at all in portrait mode.
2. The text in landscape mode
   that is scrolling is ellipsized and truncated. I would expect the
   scrolling text to show the rest of the text.

Note that I am building an AlertDialog. Below is the code:

```
public class AboutFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        String message = "Top line message";

        builder.setTitle(R.string.about_title);
        View v = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about_scrollable,null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_txt_scr);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.about_message);
        tv2.setText(message);
        tv.setSelected(true);
        tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        tv.requestFocus();
        builder.setView(v);


        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                //nothing really to be done here
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        />
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/about_txt_scr"
        android:text="A really long text that is going on and on but it actually truncated using ellipsis in this example"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:lines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below attribute for your textview 'about_txt_scr'

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_txt_scr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="A really long text that is going on and on but it actually truncated using ellipsis in this example" />
```

And comment this 2 lines from the from onCreateDialog method

```
 //tv.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
 //tv.requestFocus();
```

Comment: This is spot on. Thanks. In fact the lines that made the difference was removing `android:textIsSelectable`and the 2 java lines